# Export from MSSQL Server to an existing Excel file with formulas

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel file, filled with formulas in columns V:AG. I stretched the formulas for 10000 rows.

I would like to export something from a SQL Server table into columns A:U.

When I am trying to export through the SQL Server wizard, the export goes to row 10001.

Obviously, that's not the point..

How can I achieve that the export will start from row 2 (right behind the headers)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you tying to remove the column headers from the export so your data will start in row one?

Comment: Bit fiddly but you can use powerquery to import from SQL server and specify the range and worksheet when doing close and load to. I would start with a query bringing in a few rows so you know the shape of the range you will need to input into the load to box when it asks for the range. You can then amend the SQL query to pull more rows and refresh the powerquery.

Comment: @jradich1234, hm.. no. I want it to start from row 2 instead of 10001.

Comment: @QHarr, I need to use export, not import. with import it's easy to do..
I need it to run on a daily basis automatically. so a job that would export the data daily.